# How can I set window size in text mining using Python

Tags: python, text-mining

I'm a beginner in python and I want to solve this question.  Write a function performing the windowization of the YahooFinance sequence. The window size is the parameter `maxspan`, that you will set to 2 days (*i.e. from t = 0 to t = 2*).

I have written code but I'm thinking it is wrong.

Where am I doing wrong?

```py
def windowization(data,maxspam):
window = []
for i in data:
    window.append(i)
print(len(window))
return window
print(windowization(yahooDataset,3))
```

Comment: Do you THINK it's wrong? Or do you KNOW for a fact it's wrong? 

Also, just to note - you have a return statement before your final print statement and your function body should be indented.

Comment: I'm not sure it's wrong or not. but my output looking like just print all data

Comment: Ok. What output are you expecting then? What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks, I have done